# INSERT IGNORE using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I am trying to insert a few rows into the MySQL table using Codeigniter and Active Records.

**PHP Code**

```
$data = array('......');  // some rows of data to insert
$this->db->insert_batch('my_table', $data);
```

However this may cause duplicate rows to be inserted into the table. To handle the insertion of duplicate data, I plan to use the `INSERT IGNORE` command to not insert the row if the row is a duplicate.

**Problem:** I cannot find the `INSERT IGNORE` equivalent in Active Records and do not want to edit the Active Record class. Are there any other alternatives?

The following looks interesting, but if I do the following, wont the query be run twice?

```
$insert_query = $this->db->insert_batch('my_table', $data);  // QUERY RUNS ONCE
$insert_query = str_replace('INSERT INTO','INSERT IGNORE INTO',$insert_query);
$this->db->query($insert_query); // QUERY RUNS A SECOND TIME
```

Comment: After reading all of the answers, let me summarize - there is NO good method for doing this as a batch `:(`

Comment: I tried the INSERT IGNORE with MySQL 5.5.42 and works. However there is a side effect where the auto-increment will continue to raise even if nothing was inserted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the technique of your second idea, you could generate a query by looping over the array and using:

```
$this->db->query($query_string);
```

Comment: If you still want to run just a single SQL command to do the batch insert, you could use the following code...
`$batch_assignment = $this->db->set_insert_batch($batch_assignment);
  $query = $this->db->_insert_batch('users_to_tasks', array('task_id', 'user_id'), $this->db->ar_set);`

Answer (score 45):

Don't use `insert_batch`, as it actually runs the query.  You want [`insert_string`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/helpers.html)

```
$insert_query = $this->db->insert_string('my_table', $data);
$insert_query = str_replace('INSERT INTO','INSERT IGNORE INTO',$insert_query);
$this->db->query($insert_query);
```

**UPDATE**: This doesn't work for batch queries, only one row at a time.

Comment: Thank you @Hazmat. and for those who want to know whether inserted or ignored can use this "$this->db->insert_id();" and check if it is bigger than zero.

Answer (score 8):

As I also encountered a similar problem, I finally chose a little bit more "elegant" solution like the one below. A complete insert_batch query that is something that uses Rocket's answer AND transactions:

```
$this->db->trans_start();
foreach ($items as $item) {
       $insert_query = $this->db->insert_string('table_name', $item);
       $insert_query = str_replace('INSERT INTO', 'INSERT IGNORE INTO', $insert_query);
       $this->db->query($insert_query);
    }
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

That will also wrap everything on a transaction resulting on a faster query like doing a insert_batch(). Well not as fast as insert_batch() but faster than a single query for each entry of course. I hope it will help someone.

Comment: You'll also want to add this line `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 0` in the mysql configuration file to prevent the auto increment counter from incrementing even on ignored entries.

Answer (score 7):

For batch uploads you might need something more like:

```
foreach ($data as $data_item) {
    $insert_query = $this->db->insert_string('my_table', $data_item);
    $insert_query = str_replace('INSERT INTO', 'INSERT IGNORE INTO', $insert_query);
    $this->db->query($insert_query);
}
```

**UPDATE:** Use dcostalis's version (in the comments below this one), it will scale much better :-)

Comment: I used this as a fast solution to my problem (I insert just a small array), not sure how well this would scale with a big array.

Comment: `$sql = "";
foreach ($data as $data_item) {
    $insert_query = $this->db->insert_string('my_table', $data_item);
    $sql.= str_replace('INSERT INTO', 'INSERT IGNORE INTO', $insert_query);
}
$this->db->query($sql);
`

Answer (score 4):

This is basically a modification of Rocket Hazmat's suggestion, which is great, but doesn't take into account the fact that str_replace operates on the entire string and might inadvertently affect the data.

```
$insert_query = $this->db->insert_string('my_table', $data);
$insert_query = preg_replace('/INSERT INTO/','INSERT IGNORE INTO',$insert_query,1);
$this->db->query($insert_query);
```

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose i made this helper function:

```
function insert_batch_string($table='',$data=[],$ignore=false){
    $CI = &get_instance();
    $sql = '';

    if ($table && !empty($data)){
        $rows = [];

        foreach ($data as $row) {
            $insert_string = $CI->db->insert_string($table,$row);
            if(empty($rows) && $sql ==''){
                $sql = substr($insert_string,0,stripos($insert_string,'VALUES'));
            }
            $rows[] = trim(substr($insert_string,stripos($insert_string,'VALUES')+6));
        }

        $sql.=' VALUES '.implode(',',$rows);

        if ($ignore) $sql = str_ireplace('INSERT INTO', 'INSERT IGNORE INTO', $sql);
    }
    return $sql;
}
```

It can do batch insert and batch insert with ignore.
To avoid duplicate rows you must set a unique key in the database table for a primary field.

Answer (score 1):

solution :

```
$sql = $this->db->set($data)->get_compiled_insert($table);
$sql = str_replace('INSERT INTO', 'INSERT IGNORE INTO', $sql);
$this->db->query($sql);
```

works in codeigniter 3.0.6 :)

Comment: A very ugly work around is one solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not highly recommended but here is a hack to preserve the batch insert (which is more efficient wrt Mysql)

```
// try to insert as usual first
$this->db->insert_batch('my_table', $data);

// if it fails resort to IGNORE
if($this->db->_error_message())
{
        $sql = $this->db->last_query();
        $sql = str_replace('INSERT INTO', 'INSERT IGNORE INTO', $sql);
        $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

Comment: im using ajax, and still i get the duplicate error.. :(
I dont want to get the duplicate error, just move to insert ignore if duplicate exist..

Comment: what happens on the browser will not affect mysql behavior. did you try the method i proposed? if you want to supress db errors then adjust the db config settings. if you handle the error the insert should go through.

Answer (score 0):

I too had same issue what helped me is :

Open : **Codeigniter/system/database/DB_query_builder.php** :

find

```
protected function _insert_batch($table, $keys, $values)
    {
        return 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' ('.implode(', ', $keys).') VALUES '.implode(', ', $values);
    }
```

and replace with :

```
protected function _insert_batch($table, $keys, $values)
{
    return 'INSERT IGNORE INTO '.$table.' ('.implode(', ', $keys).') VALUES '.implode(', ', $values);
}
```

Comment: This would work, but isn't a great solution.  as soon as a CI update comes along that you don't remember to do this you have generated a problem..

Answer (score 0):

add to file DB_query_builder.php

this 2 functions

```
public function insert_ignore_batch($table = '', $set = NULL, $escape = NULL) {
    if ($set !== NULL)
    {
        $this->set_insert_batch($set, '', $escape);
    }

    if (count($this->qb_set) === 0)
    {
        // No valid data array. Folds in cases where keys and values did not match up
        return ($this->db_debug) ? $this->display_error('db_must_use_set') : FALSE;
    }

    if ($table === '')
    {
        if ( ! isset($this->qb_from[0]))
        {
            return ($this->db_debug) ? $this->display_error('db_must_set_table') : FALSE;
        }

        $table = $this->qb_from[0];
    }

    // Batch this baby
    $affected_rows = 0;
    for ($i = 0, $total = count($this->qb_set); $i < $total; $i += 100)
    {
        $this->query($this->_insert_ignore_batch($this->protect_identifiers($table, TRUE, $escape, FALSE), $this->qb_keys, array_slice($this->qb_set, $i, 100)));
        $affected_rows += $this->affected_rows();
    }

    $this->_reset_write();
    return $affected_rows;
}

protected function _insert_ignore_batch($table, $keys, $values) {
    return 'INSERT IGNORE INTO '.$table.' ('.implode(', ', $keys).') VALUES '.implode(', ', $values);
}
```

using:

```
$this->db->insert_ignore_batch('TableName', $data);
```

Comment: will this cause to ignore other error that are not necessary duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

If still someone is struggling with insert_batch to use ignore,

Check this path,

```
system/database/DB_query_builder.php
```

Search for function

```
protected function _insert_batch
```

Change

```
INSERT INTO => INSERT IGNORE INTO
```

Thank me later. :)

Comment: It may work, but changing system files is not very cool

Answer (score 0):

Avoid duplicate data insertion in codeigniter is a tricky task. But you can ignore duplicate values insertion using customized library method in very simple and accurate way.
I have found a suitable solution at:
[how-to-avoid-duplicate-data-insertion-in-codeigniter-php](https://gulpoint.com/how-to-avoid-duplicate-data-insertion-in-codeigniter-php/)

Answer (score -1):

Avoid duplicate rows by setting a unique key in the database table for at least one of the fields.

Comment: Will this cause an error to occur when trying to insert a duplicate row?

Comment: Not if you set the database.php config variable for 'debug' to false.

Comment: The error is still generated, codeigniter just ignores it; this is not a great solution