# Continue query execution if one query in batch fails in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, batch-insert

I am trying to insert around 3000 rows using codeigniter batch insert but problem is , if one row in a batch fails it stops execution of other rows  and prints that query error.

Is it possible to continue execution ,even if there is a failed query in a batch and log that failed query ?

I don't want to use $this>db->query since it takes lot more time and connections than $this->db->insert_batch(); Also this insert operation is a cron script which runs every 5 min so using the fastest way is more preferable since this insert operations are carried on a transactional database.

Comment: Yes you can, refer the link:

[Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965792/insert-ignore-using-codeigniter

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37758/inline-links-in-comments

Comment: I dont want to  user $this->db->query() since its takes lot more time than $this->db->insert_batch().

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about CI, but I'd use the exception class

Something like :

```
<?php
try{
    // YOUR PHP CODE
} catch(Exception $e){
    // IF AN ERROR OCCURS, PRINT, LOG, etc...
    print_r($e);
}
?>
```