# How to add INSERT IGNORE INTO in Codeigniter batch insert query

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to make codeigniter function that works same as insert_batch() but generates query Like INSERT IGNORE INTO ?

I need `INSERT IGNORE INTO` because one of my table's key is unique and its showing error when duplicate entry comes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [INSERT IGNORE using Codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965792/insert-ignore-using-codeigniter)

Comment: @ Gunaseelan : means this INSERT IGNORE will add duplicate rows into table ?

Comment: will not add duplicate rows.

Comment: So I need this because I don't want my script to stop while batch insert that's why I use it.
you have better solution of this ?

Comment: I am not flagged this answer as duplicate. I just flagged the question only. I am really happy to see a solution to this

Comment: @Gunaseelan : Thanks but I didn't found this type of solution on net that's why I posted this. I am not able to see who have gave negative flag to my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84784/discussion-between-ronak-chauhan-and-gunaseelan).

Answer (score 4):

I searched code for add "INSERT IGNORE INTO " instead of "INSERT INTO" in codeigniter batch insert query but I didn't found results for that.
Yes we can made our custom batch insert query by using PHP login But if you want to do it in codeigniter use this function.

Add this function in (codeigniter/system/database/DB_active.rec.php).

```
/*
*Function For Batch Insert using Ignore Into
*/
public function custom_insert_batch($table = '', $set = NULL)
{
    if ( ! is_null($set))
    {
        $this->set_insert_batch($set);
    }

    if (count($this->ar_set) == 0)
    {
        if ($this->db_debug)
        {
            //No valid data array.  Folds in cases where keys and values did not match up
            return $this->display_error('db_must_use_set');
        }
        return FALSE;
    }

    if ($table == '')
    {
        if ( ! isset($this->ar_from[0]))
        {
            if ($this->db_debug)
            {
                return $this->display_error('db_must_set_table');
            }
            return FALSE;
        }

        $table = $this->ar_from[0];
    }

    // Batch this baby
    for ($i = 0, $total = count($this->ar_set); $i < $total; $i = $i + 100)
    {

        $sql = $this->_insert_batch($this->_protect_identifiers($table, TRUE, NULL, FALSE), $this->ar_keys, array_slice($this->ar_set, $i, 100));
        $sql = str_replace('INSERT INTO','INSERT IGNORE INTO',$sql);
        //echo $sql;

        $this->query($sql);
    }

    $this->_reset_write();


    return TRUE;
}
```

To use this function

```
$this->db->custom_insert_batch($table_name, $batch_data);
```

Thanks !

Comment: You should not modify the files in the system folder