# How to prevent duplicate records from getting re-inserted into table AND avoid Exception Duplicate key name constraints on reloading page

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I tried using `ALTER IGNORE TABLE employee ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_employee UNIQUE (ename,dno,mgr,sal)`.

And it worked perfectly for avoiding duplicate entries until I tested it by reloading the page. I suppose it is trying to say that there can not be another key name like the one used previously, that was constraint_employee.
So is there a way I can reload the page without any re insertion and without any errors and exceptions?

I am implementing and facing this issue while applying this in CodeIgniter in the form of `$this->db->query(" ... my query ... ");` in the model file.

```php
$this->db->query(" ... my query ... ");
```

```
Uncaught Exception: Duplicate entry
```

Comment: Seeing the code would help. FWIW: [INSERT IGNORE using Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965792/insert-ignore-using-codeigniter) Sounds like you just need to handle the exception though! Suggest you read up on race conditions / locking / transactions to have a better understanding of this.

Comment: Please note that `ALTER IGNORE TABLE` is deprecated and has been removed as of version 5.7.4 (five years ago): https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/143862/mysql-alter-ignore-add-index-removed-in-mysql-5-7-4-what-to-use-instead